# How to pull a IP out of a string using preg_match in PHP:?

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a log file which I want to pull IP's out of. I have tried this using `preg_match()` but it never finds a match. Here is my attempt:

```
$str = 'Jan  7 01:11:58 vps.... sshd[14799]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 11.22.333.444 port 52636 [preauth]';

if (preg_match('/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/', $str, $ip_matches)) {
    var_dump($ip_matches);
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't use `^` and `$` when you are searching for a substring because they match the start and end of the string respectively and your string is not just an ip address. Try this `/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/` instead.

Comment: @bassxzero this fixed it! if you post an answer, ill be sure to mark it. Thanks so much!

Comment: 127.000.000.001 is not an IP address.

Comment: @jaquarh This question was closed as a duplicate so I can't post an answer.